# Nimbus internal frame don't increase height

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jinternalframe, nimbus

I'm trying to set the default font size with:

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("defaultFont", new Font("DejaVU Sans", Font.PLAIN, 24));
```

But the height of the jInternalFrame doesn't increase like in the picture (Left example).
[image]
How can I increase the font of the jInternalFrame and have the looks like the right example (but with the bigger font size and the jInternalFrame title bar higher and the dropdown button also inside the title bar)?

**Edit**

Tried with

```
Container pane = ((BasicInternalFrameUI) ift.getUI()).getNorthPane();
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pane.getPreferredSize().width, 70));
```

To see if I could increase the height of the jInternalFrame title bar but got this instead
[image]

As you can see what I got was a tittle bar with the same size but the NothPane increased and now the text is bellow the title bar.

Thanks